# How to train an ML model to generate predictions for multiple regions in one image

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, gcloud

I am working on a home project helping out a friend of mine who runs a factory with 4 loading docks. He has a camera that can see all 4 loading docks. We want to create a model to take the image and say bay 1 occupied, bay 2 free, bay 3 blocked ect...

I have played with ML a little bit before and have managed to create a model that can tell me that my garage door is open. The difficulty here is that I want to train the model with 4 different statuses in each image and when the model is up and running I want it to identify each loading bay in the image and give me the status of each.

I am hoping that the AI can do this all for me but I realise I might need to do more work for it!

Another option was that I could split the images up so that each image was sliced into 4, I could then just feed the prediction model an image and ask for 1 status back. Is this a more sensible approach (despite it being a pain for me to do this automatically)?

Comment: The 2 options are good. The 2nd, you could train a first model to box and extract each bay from the image, and then another model that determine the occupation. Else, you can have only 1 model and to get the status of each bay. Then it's a post processing that extract the position in the image (the bounding box of the bay) and the status.

Comment: thanks, the bounding boxes for the areas will not change as it's a fixed camera. I think that I am quite close to figuring out how to extract an image of each area from the main image.

Comment: If the bay are "similar" you will need a smaller traning set if you split the frame and perform inference on each bay than having a full pict.

Comment: yes, I was thinking that the ML would probbaly be much simpler. I can use images from all the bays to train for all the bays I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, going by 2nd option: you can split the images based on the fixed bounding boxes of the four bay and train your model on that data. You can refer to this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/extraction-of-objects-in-images-and-videos-using-5-lines-of-code-6a9e35677a31) which discusses extracting objects from a picture, and as mentioned by @guillaume if your bays are similar you will require much less data. You can then use extracted images from all bays and perform prediction.